# ASCollectionNode full-width layout for CellNode

Tags: ios, swift, asyncdisplaykit

I want to make cells full-width in `ASCollectionNode`, but I'll get `CellNodes` sized by content.
I have implemented `layoutSpecThatFits:`.

[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CVXT.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My way to achieve that is adding extra node with full width inside ASStaticLayoutSpec.

In header:

`@property (strong, nonatomic) ASDisplayNode *stretchNode;`

In init

`_stretchNode = [ASDisplayNode new];
[self addSubnode:_stretchNode];`

layoutSpecThatFits:

```
- (ASLayoutSpec *)layoutSpecThatFits:(ASSizeRange)constrainedSize {
    _stretchNode.sizeRange = ASRelativeSizeRangeMakeWithExactCGSize(CGSizeMake(constrainedSize.max.width, 0.5f));

    NSArray *children = @[];

    ASStackLayoutSpec *mainStackLayoutSpec = [ASStackLayoutSpec stackLayoutSpecWithDirection:ASStackLayoutDirectionVertical spacing:0 justifyContent:ASStackLayoutJustifyContentStart alignItems:ASStackLayoutAlignItemsStart children:children];
    ASStaticLayoutSpec *mainStaticLayoutSpec = [ASStaticLayoutSpec staticLayoutSpecWithChildren:@[mainInsetsLayoutSpec, _stretchNode]];

    return mainStaticLayoutSpec;
}
```

Important part here is to wrap your layout and stretchNode in ASStaticLayoutSpec. You can replace StackLayout with anything you want.